# How to deploy Laravel 10 Project to AWS App Runner via github source code

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-10, aws-app-runner

I tried to deploy laravel 10 (php 8.1) Project to AWS app runner via github source code but I faced creation issue.

- I created service.
- Repository Type: Source Code Repository
- I connect project from github.
- Deployment Trigger: Automatic
- Configuration File: Configure all settings here.
- Runtime: PHP 8.1
- PORT: 80
- Build Command: composer install
- Start Command: php artisan serve

I checked the log.
After installing composer packages, it says composer command not found

[image]

Error screenshot

[image]

So I removed composer install command from build Command then, it didn't install composer packages (vendor) automatically, Project doens't run.
How to resolve this?
Anyone knows how to deploy laravel 10 project to aws app runner via above steps?
Thanks

How to deploy Laravel 10 Project to AWS app runner?

Comment: Did you create a docker image for your laravel project and push it into AWS ECR to use it?

Comment: @ArpitJain, I am not using ECR, I used AWS default PHP runtime.

Comment: AWS App Runner is a container application service, so I think it is supposed to be run with docker images.

Answer (score 1):

I have shared my experience of deploying a Laravel app on AWS EC2 in the following article. I hope that you may find some useful information in this article.

[How to Deploy a Laravel App on AWS EC2 Ubuntu?](https://ravitaxali.medium.com/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-app-on-aws-ec2-ubuntu-9a5b3d0999d8)